# Trouble getting RPI wireless card into monitor mode

Tags: raspbian, wireless

I have an RPI Model B with a wireless card, Belkin N150 Rev.B01

I am having a tough time getting airmon to work or setting wlan0 to monitor mode.

I am able to use wicd to connect to my wireless network at home and use the internet from my RPI with 0 setup.

A little more information, when I issue the command, "iwconfig wlan0 mode monitor" I receive an error

```
Error for wireless request "Set Mode" (8B06) :
    SET failed on device wlan0 ; Invalid argument.
```

I suspect that this is some sort of driver issue? I'm not really sure where to start to get the wireless card into monitor mode... Any pointers on how to accomplish this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What chipset does that stick have ?
lsusb should tell you
It may be possible that the stick doesn't support monitor mode.

if you install the iw package, and then run `iw list` (with the space in the middle), it will tell you whether it supports monitor mode.